# Random fire position between points (sets from a vector direction and point)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

This is my first question here.
For my weapon code in my 2D shooter i have a direction vector formed between two points (Base and Emitter) and a point (C) where i put rifle sight.

I'm trying to implement a sort of precision cone (random shot between two points, equidistant from point C forming a perpendicular line to direction vector)

Here's the scheme:

[image]

The position of points L and R are not defined yet.
I need an help for:

- Define position of L and R given Distance vector (Emitter-Base) and C
- Random point between L and R

I tried without success so i'm asking for an help.
Thanks in advance.
Regards

Comment: Are the points supposed to lie on the same plane? Or do you want an actual cone?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html

Comment: Yes @theodox Same plane, 2D

Comment: Why don't you just use an empty object. Fire it in the forward direction until it reaches the position of the emitter, then fire the secondary projectile in a random forward direction between the current direction +/- 30 degrees, or whatever angle you want.

Comment: @Tyler i don't know how to do what you said. Can voi provide a sample code?

Comment: Yeah. Give me a moment to write it.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to give you a bit of a simplified example. This one is assuming that when you fire a bullet it will go in a random direction inside a predefined a cone.

```
Public GameObject bulletPrefab;
Public GameObject pointOnGunBulletShootsFrom; // In your image this would be the emitter
private float halfAngleofCone = 30f; // In your image this would be the distance between C and L.
private float bulletSpeedModifier = 100f; // If you have another way of propelling your bullets you can remove this and the addforce section.

private void FireBulletInsideCone()
{
   GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, pointOnGunBulletShootsFrom.transform.position, pointOnGunBulletShootsFrom.transform.rotation);
   float angleToAdjustBy = Random.Range(0,halfAngleofCone);
   bullet.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * angleToAdjustBy );
   bullet.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward * bulletSpeedModifier);
}

void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
       FireBulletInsideCone();
    }
}
```

Here is a picture of how you may have to set up your gun. To keep things clean you may want to add a gameobject at the front of your gun facing forward to act as the `GameObject pointOnGunBulletShootsFrom` 
that the script uses. In your case this may already be accounted for by your emitter. 
[image]

Comment: Let me know if it works or if you have any issues. I use something similar in my unity3d project. I don't know how this translates over to unity2d, but I think that not much will have changed.